# PublishingPageContentOWSHTML not displayed properly in content search query

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, content-search-web-part

I am using standard out of the box templates of Content search query types and while using the attribute PublishingPageContentOWSHTML to display the text of the page (what is in the 'Page content' area). I see that the text does not 'wrap' and therefore looks 'cut' on the side.

Is this normal behaviour? Can I change something to show the text displayed properly?